# How can I make Krusader show real size of symlinked files?

Tags: files, symlink, size, file-manager

In the "size" column in Krusader, there is a link's size noted, instead of the size of the actual file. This is the same as what *ls -l* shows (the full address of the target file, e.g. 64 B instead of 3.4 kB in one particular case). Is there a way how to change this to show the size of the target file?
[image: The selected file is an actual file, the others are symlinks to similar-sized files]